# Parameter Query using SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to make a SQLite SQL query using parameters and for some reason its not working (i have done this with an OLE db before successfully). I took the below syntax from a google search but doesnt seem to be working.

It doesnt seem to like my command.perameter.add line and its giving me a "SQLite is not accessible due to its protection level" error.

I imagine its me converting from OLE to SQLlite syntax that is causing the issue but im not sure. Any ideas? My code is as below:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Jobs (jEnquiryNumber) VALUES (@jEnquiryNumber)";
MessageBox.Show(sql);

SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, dbConnectString);
using (command)
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@jEnquiryNumber", SQLiteType.Text).Value = textBox1.Text;
            
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message? The bit you posted doesn't seem to have any relation to that line of code

Comment: SQLiteCommand doesn't have a constructor that takes to strings. The second parameter is meant to be a SQLiteConnection. Is this a compile time error you are getting?

Comment: The error as it reads is as follows: CS0122 'SQLiteType' is inaccessible due to its protection level.  

How do i tell if its a compile error?

Comment: Right! That's different to what you said in your question, which was "SQLite is not accessible"

Comment: What SQLite library are you using? `System.Data.Sqlite` and `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` use `SqliteCommand` rather than `SQLiteCommand`